# How can I replace a loop with vectorized code?

Tags: r, loops

This Q comes without a reproducible example.

I have a $n \times m$ matrix `M`. And I have a function `fun`, which takes, besides several other arguments, a column of `M` as input. `fun()$var1` returns a vector.

`result` is again a matrix with the same number of columens but a different number of rows.

This loop works but is slow:

```
for(i in 1:ncol(M)) result[, i] <- fun(x, b, y, r, M[, i])$var1
```

What is a vectorized alternative (e.g. from the *`apply()`-family)?

Comment: It is a common but incorrect belief that the apply function are going to vectorize operations. They are just for-loops in disguise. The Vectorize function is only a wrapper for mapply. Your goal instead should be optimizing the code in your function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Vectorize`.
Let's say `fun` has `x, b, y, r, M` arguments

```
funV <- Vectorize(FUN = fun,vectorize.args = 'M')
result[,1:m] <- funV(x, b, y, r, M[, 1:m])$var1
```

If you look at source code of `Vectorize` by typing `Vectorize`+`Return` in console, you'll see that it handles `mapply` to answer your question:

```
 do.call("mapply", c(FUN = FUN, args[dovec], MoreArgs = list(args[!dovec]), 
        SIMPLIFY = SIMPLIFY, USE.NAMES = USE.NAMES))
```

Comment: Looks promising, but does not work. Throws an error: `non-conformable arrays` taking place inside `ifelse()` relying on the input  `r` (a vector). Could you guess sth. without having a reproducible example?

Comment: Has it sth. to do with "ignoring" `$var1`?

Comment: @Pax. You are unlikely to get effective help unless you provide the code and data for your problem.

Comment: I forgot var1, but it should work, see my edit. Should, because as you pointed out, without reproducible example, difficult to test.